# Doesn't boot after installing fglrx for ati 5650

Tags: 10.04, drivers, graphics, ati, fglrx

I'm a complete noob here, I recently bought an HP 3161 with an ATI 5650 hd card, when I installed 10.04 LTS everything was working fine until I was prompted to activate proprietary driver fglrx, after I did this I couldn't reboot (not even in recovery mode) until I reinstalled 10.04, what can I do?

I would appreciate any help since I haven't been able to find anyone with the same problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution below, if you ever have this again, you can simply uninstall **fglrx** via terminal. I had a similar issue with my 4670 and **fglrx**. After I installed it and activated the driver, it would not boot.

Follow this [Natty Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx) (there may be other methods around).

Once that is done, run:

```
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and if you are logged in as your own account on terminal, just add `sudo`.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware specs are like mine (Intel/ATI Radeon HD 5650, switchable graphics), then know that the fglrx driver currently does not support systems with switchable graphics, and not much can be done about it now since the driver is proprietary.

Your only option is to use the open source radeon driver (which currently doesn't support 3d acceleration AFAIK), or wait until fglrx is updated to support switchable graphics.

**UPDATE**

AMD has released an [updated driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) 
 (11.5 as of this edit) that finally supports switchable graphics. I highly recommend using the [instructions](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu) for your version of Ubuntu.

I used the instructions for 11.04 Natty and Catalyst 11.5 and the installation was smooth and successful. I suggest reading the page thoroughly before proceeding so that you know how to recover in case something doesn't go well.

Comment: Hey thank you very much I really had a difficult time trying to figure out what was the issue, and I just decided to wait and see if it got solved, I'm also now having to use W :( for 3D stuff, I hope the open source driver gets updated soon.

Comment: Though these drivers add support for switchable graphics they won't work on the intel/ati muxless system that the ATI 5650 Mobility Radeon is (or to be more precise: this possibility was removed for those type of cards in later releases again).